# Error al sumar valores de un Foreach en la vista MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Actualmente tengo un error al sumar unos valores de un foreach, la vista es de extencion **.cshtml** razor en C#, el código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
              <!-- Default panel contents -->
              <div class="panel-heading">CC</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                              <table class="table" style="width:100%">
                                <thead style="background-color:#d6e7ee">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>cc</th>
                                        <th>Moneda</th>
                                        <th>Porcentaje</th>
                                        <th>Costo</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody style="background-color:#f1f8f8" >
                                    @{
                                        Double TotalPorcentaje=0;
                                        Double TotalCosto=0;
                                        foreach (var item in Model.ListarCostos)
                                        {
                                            <text>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@item.strNombreCentrocosto</td>
                                                    <td>@item.strSimboloMoneda</td>
                                                    <td>@item.nPercentageCentroCosto %</td>
                                                    <td>@item.nCosto</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                TotalPorcentaje=TotalPorcentaje+@item.nPercentageCentroCosto;
                                                TotalCosto=TotalCosto+@item.nCosto;
                                            </text>                                
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @{
                                        <text>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2"><strong>TOTAL:</strong></td>
                                                    <td><strong>TotalPorcentaje</strong></td>
                                                    <td><strong>TotalCosto</strong></td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </text>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Alguien puede darme algunas referencias de la sintaxis correcta, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si mencionas que se produce un error se agradecerá nos proporciones el mensaje del mismo, no todas las excepciones son evidentes con sólo leer el código.

Respecto al código que adjuntas, sugiero obtener los totales mediante el método de extensión Sum() y pintarlos en la sección 'tfoot', por ejemplo:

```
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>@Model.ListarCostos.Sum(x => x.nPercentageCentroCosto)</strong></td>
        <td><strong>@Model.ListarCostos.Sum(x => x.MaBRID)</strong></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Puedes aplicar formato de presentación a los resultados mediante el método .ToString("P2|N2").

Comment: #Williams, funciono correctamente, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Las expresiones de linea se utilizan para imprimir datos al cliente, no para hacer operaciones con ellas. Tambien deberias de mover la operacion de suma afuera de la etiqueta `text` para que puedas hacer la operacion sin utilizar codigo de bloque.

Reemplaza:

```
//...
</tr>                                                
  TotalPorcentaje=TotalPorcentaje+@item.nPercentageCentroCosto;                                              
  TotalCosto=TotalCosto+@item.nCosto;
</text>  
//..
```

Por:

```
   //...
    </tr>    
   </text>                                            
    TotalPorcentaje=TotalPorcentaje + item.nPercentageCentroCosto;                                              
    TotalCosto=TotalCosto + item.nCosto;
   //..
```